# Is it possible to save a KDE desktop configuration?

Tags: kde, backup, settings, plasma

Is it possible to save a desktop configuration while using KDE Plasma Desktop?

I mean, I have customized my desktop with a set of plasmoids, each with its own custom settings, and I'd like to save the state of the whole Desktop in order to restore it when I want to.

For what I've seen, some of these plasmoids can have their preferences saved and restored, but each of these work on its own.

I can't find any option from the Plasma GUI, it's just me or this is simply not possible?

Anyway, even without the GUI, these setting should be saved somewhere in my system, I.E. to restore the Desktop to its current state whenever I boot up the system. Where can I find them?

Comment: Check the `/var/tmp/kdecache-yourname` folder (it might be located somewhere else on your system)

Answer (score 1):

Old question but still needed. I've been using [Plasma Customization Saver](https://store.kde.org/p/1298955/) plasmoid and it seems to work ok.

From the plasmoid description:

> This is a widget that allows you to save your current plasma customization and choose between all the customizations you saved to load them again.
>
> Features:
>   - Saving your current plasma customization (theme, window decoration, colors, icons, wallpapers, layout disposition, widgets etc...)
>
> - Having multiple saved customization and easy switch between them.
> - Save and restore your latte-dock customization per save
> - It saves a screenshot of every customization so you can visually identified them.
> - Explort and import customizations. For transfer to another computer or backup them.

Answer (score 0):

I've had trouble with the Plasma Customization Saver widget mentioned in @sanzante's answer; another option is [Konsave](https://github.com/Prayag2/konsave), which is a simple Python utility that allows you to save, export, and apply configurations. And you can switch between configurations in a single session, so you can test out if it will work for you.